# Multiple require('express') in node.js

Tags: node.js, express

In my node.js app has require('express') in every controller (js files). Is that many express object will create a problem when it goes live??

or

i need to send one express object across all js file through argument. which one is best. please suggest me.

Comment: `require('express')` is not necessarily the same as an _"express object"_ (the result of `express()`). Which do you mean, exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you use require("express"), then node.js checks if the module is in the memory, it will not access it  from storage and use it. So multiple object wont be created.

Comment: OK, but if the project a normally set up, where *server > app > route > controller*, there should be just one correct spot to require express, isn't it?

Comment: No. Your routers need to import express for express.Router()